# How to trigger 'select' event in jQuery UI Selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I got this selectmenu:

```
$( "#software" ).selectmenu({ 
    width : 'auto', 
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        //my code
    }
});
```

And I want to programmatically change the selected Item and trigger the 'select' state.

I do the following:

```
$( "#software" ).val( 1 ).selectmenu( "refresh" ).trigger( "select" );
```

The selectmenu picks the right option and refreshes it but it doesn't trigger the 'select' state. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following:-

```js
$( "#software" ).val(1).selectmenu("refresh").trigger("selectmenuselect");
```

You will need to bind an event listener to the selectmenuselect event like:

```js
$( "#software" ).on( "selectmenuselect", function( event, ui ) {
     alert('New Item Selected!')
});
```

Info: [`select( event, ui )`](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-select)

Comment: I want not do "$( "#software" ).val(1)", I just want to fire trigger every time when I change the value.